# Ampscript for multi language: date format in code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formatting

I am a beginner in AMPscript and I am facing an issue.
I would like to convert a date format into the customer language.
For now, I was able to convert the format from "xx/xx/xxxx" into "DD MMMM YYYY" doing this:

```
SET @EB1_End_Date_Formated = FormatDate(@EB1_End_Date, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "en-US")
SET @Opening_Date_Formated = FormatDate(@Opening_Date_Formated, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "en-US")
```

but now I would like the formatted date to be translated into the customer language for it to do:

- English: 21 december 2021
- French: 21 décembre 2021

Can you please help me with this? I cannot find the exact code to enter anywhere.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You basically have everything to achieve the desired result. Since you already have the English date version, then that is how the [FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/) function would look for the French version, you just change the 4th and last argument to the ISO locale code -

```
/* I gave a new name for French variables */
SET @EB1_End_Date_Formated_FR = FormatDate(@EB1_End_Date, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "fr-FR")
SET @Opening_Date_Formated_FR = FormatDate(@Opening_Date_Formated, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "fr-FR)
```

You can find the list of all existing in Marketing Cloud locales [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_data_extension_locales.htm&type=5).

A small tip on top, you can use [ProperCase](https://ampscript.guide/propercase/) function to make sure the month's name will be always starting with a capital letter -

```
SET @EB1_End_Date_Formated_FR = ProperCase(FormatDate(@EB1_End_Date, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "fr-FR"))
SET @Opening_Date_Formated_FR = ProperCase(FormatDate(@Opening_Date_Formated, "DD MMMM YYYY","", "fr-FR))
```

Comment: thanks a lot Niko! However I don't know how to place it within my ampscript for it to work, it seems something is missing... I just put it after the EN ? nothing more?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your issue correctly. You need to change only the last 4th argument in the function to another ISO locale. "en-US" --> "fr-FR" as an example. What is the problem with the placement though?

Comment: @AndreaJuan so have you solved your problem?